# Size Limit for "AWS::Include"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

To setup our `API-Gateway` via cloudformation, we're using `Fn::transform` with `AWS::include` to load the open-api specification into it and replace some parameters via cloudformation parameters.
However, as we're growing the api, we've been hit with cloudformation bailing out on us:

```
"ResourceStatusReason": "Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:...:stack/lZYW/UUID was not successfully updated. 
Currently in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS with reason: 
  Transform AWS::Include failed with: The specified S3 object is too big.",
```

The filesize is 455kb in this case, so the limit for `AWS::Include` seems to still be the 450kb limit. In other place this limit was lifted some time ago (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/aws-cloudformation-now-supports-increased-limits-on-five-service-quotas/).

Does anybody know a way around this or how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!